# How to replace an XML node via python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am new in python and I have a - maybe - stupid problem with XML files (yep, I've tried to google the solution but without results).

I have to write a program which will replace/switch two things, so first of all, here is the XML data, it looks like this:

```
<data='qwerty'>
    <name_it>some_name</name_it>
</data>

<next_data='next_qwerty'>
    <name_it>another_name</name_it>
</next_data>

<next_next_data>
...
</next_next_data>
<next_xyz_data>...
etc.
```

How in python i could change `some_name` to be in `data=''`?
So it should be like this:

```
<data='some_name'>                            #changed from 'qwerty' to some_name
    <name_it>some_name</name_it>
</data>

<next_data='another_name'>                    #changed from 'next_qwerty' to another_name
    <name_it>another_name</name_it>
</next_data>
```

If it's a stupid question, sorry about that, but I truly googled it and I cannot find a solution.

UPDATE:
Here is the few lines of python code that I wrote:

```
from xml_file import data

new=""

f = io.StringIO(data)  # data loading
for r in f: 
    row = r.rstrip() 
    if 'name_it' in row: 
        change = row[row.index('name_it')] # maybe kind of len() or something
    if "<data>" in row and change: 
        idx = row.index("<data>") + 6
        new += row[:idx] + change + "name_it=\n"
        change = ""  
    else:
        new += row + "\n" # new line
```

And here is true XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="Setup">
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="xxx">
        <data>abc_qwe</data>                       #change_me_to_"xxx"
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="yyy">
        <data>xyzzzz</data>                        #change_me_to_"yyy"
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

There are many of the  signs.
Just `<data>...</data>` name should be in `name="..."`

Alright, so here are the content of files.
First of all I am generating CSV file:

```
Type,Name,Request Count,Failure Count,Median Response Time,Average Response Time,Min Response Time,Max Response Time,Average Content Size,Requests/s,Failures/s,50%,66%,75%,80%,90%,95%,98%,99%,99.9%,99.99%,99.999%,100%
POST,---ON START---LOGIN,33,0,2023.709774017334,2037.008133801547,2023.709774017334,2058.631658554077,6587.515151515152,0.24352046353820625,0.0,2000,2000,2000,2000,2100,2100,2100,2100,2100,2100,2100,2100
GET,Aggregations,15,0,4,5.305735270182292,3.652334213256836,11.571884155273438,6174.2,0.11069111979009376,0.0,4,5,7,7,9,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
GET,Alarms,5,0,5,4.584074020385742,3.754138946533203,5.759000778198242,6173.8,0.03689703993003125,0.0,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
GET,Analysis Templates,16,0,7,7.806003093719482,3.8690567016601562,13.520479202270508,6174.625,0.11807052777610001,0.0,9,11,11,11,12,14,14,14,14,14,14,14
GET,Boiler Efficiency,15,0,6,6.464735666910808,3.6771297454833984,15.489578247070312,6174.2,0.11069111979009376,0.0,6,6,8,11,11,15,15,15,15,15,15,15
GET,Configuration,14,0,5,6.087354251316616,3.6630630493164062,12.647390365600586,6174.428571428572,0.1033117118040875,0.0,5,6,8,11,11,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
```

Then, I want to change it to be a XML:

```
import _csv
from locust_script import methods_count
with open('locust_stats.csv') as f, open('locus_statistics.csv', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        if not line.isspace():
            print(line.strip())
            out.write(line)

stats = open('locus_statistics.csv')
csv_f = _csv.reader(stats)
data = []
for row in csv_f:
    data.append(row)

def convert_row(row, methods):
    case_name = methods[0]
    del methods[0]

    return """
            <testcase classname="test_perf" name="%s">
                <Type>%s</Type>
                <Name>%s</Name>
                <Request_Count>%s</Request_Count>
                <Failure_Count>%s</Failure_Count>
                <Median_Response_Time>%s</Median_Response_Time>
            </testcase>""" % (case_name, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
report_save = open('parsed.xml', 'w')
case_name = methods_count()
report_save.write("<testsuite name='performance'>"+''.join([convert_row(row, case_name) for row in data[1:1000]])+"</testsuite>")
report_save.close()
```

Finally, I want to have parsed XML, so as I wrote above, I have trying to use this kind of script:

```
from xml_file import data

new=""

f = io.StringIO(data)  # data loading
for r in f: 
    row = r.rstrip() 
    if 'name_it' in row: 
        change = row[row.index('name_it')] # maybe kind of len() or something
    if "<data>" in row and change: 
        idx = row.index("<data>") + 6
        new += row[:idx] + change + "name_it=\n"
        change = ""  
    else:
        new += row + "\n" # new line
```

So my intention is here - i think :) -:

```
            <testcase classname="test_perf" name="%s">
                <Type>%s</Type>
                <Name>%s</Name>
```

`name=""`
should be the same as `<Name> HERE </Name>`

Comment: start by sharing 1) A valid xml document 2) python code that shows what you did so far

Comment: I think XML structure it's not necessarly in here. I've updated my question post with python code.

Comment: You can do it using XML parsing. If you will share a valid XML doc - I will be able to guide you.

Comment: Here you go, I've putted in few lines of junit report :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<testsuite name="Setup">
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="xxx">
        <data>abc_qwe</data>                      
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="yyy">
        <data>xyzzzz</data>                       
    </testcase>
</testsuite>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
test_cases = root.findall('.//testcase')
for test_case in test_cases:
    test_case.find('./data').text = test_case.attrib['name']
    
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<testsuite name="Setup">
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="xxx">
        <data>xxx</data>                      
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="yyy">
        <data>yyy</data>                       
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

The other way (set the value of the name attribute with the text of data)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<testsuite name="Setup">
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="xxx">
        <data>data_1</data>                      
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="yyy">
        <data>data_2</data>                       
    </testcase>
</testsuite>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
test_cases = root.findall('.//testcase')
for test_case in test_cases:
    test_case.attrib['name'] = test_case.find('./data').text
    
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: I see the point, but what if I have 1000 testcases? Maybe some iteration over them? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: As you can see, the code does not care if you have 2 testcases or 1000. If  my solution helps - feel free to vote up.

Comment: You are ofcourse right, but what's about this iteration in `new_values` list?
If we will have 1000 values I need to add their names manually so there is no point here :/
Check this out:
`new_values=[1,2,3,4,5,1231231,avasvas,qweeqw,123123526354,34342342...n]`

Comment: Only you (or the logic of your software) can tell the logic of replacing the values. Try to explain the logic of the replacement and maybe there is a smart way to do it.

Comment: Updated one more time. Sorry for the mess

Comment: So data should be the same as the value of the name attribute?

Comment: That's right. Excelly.
When you see these:
```
    <testcase classname="Configuration" name="xxx">
        <data>new_val_1</data>  
```
`new_val_1` should be in `name=` attr

Comment: one more thing, how to do it vice versa?
I mean - now we have <data></data> named from testcase name=...,
So how i need to modificate your script to testcase name=...from <data></data>?
I've tried something like that but it is not working:
```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
test_cases = root.findall('./data')
for test_case in test_cases:
    test_case.find('.//testcase').text = test_case.attrib['name']
```

Comment: Now you want to change the value of  name attribute according to the text of data?

Comment: Yes, that's right. How to make a modification? I am quite new in XML parsing :/

Comment: One, and the last question.
I want to grab some data from another file and assign it to `xml=` variable, how to make it happen?
I was trying to do it like this, but receiving IObuffer err:
```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('report.xml', 'rb') as xml:
    root = ET.fromstring(xml).read()
    test_cases = root.findall('.//testcase')
    for test_case in test_cases:
        test_case.attrib['name'] = test_case.find('./data').text
    
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Read a file: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#module-xml.etree.ElementTree  `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()`